# upload images to server using volley

Tags: php, android, android-volley

i have a problem in php code...can anyone change my php code to upload image and update all data when user update their profile. i have a save button to update all data...

```
public function profileUpdate($fname, $lname, $email, $mobile,  $uid, $profile_pic){
    $result = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE unique_id = '$uid'") 
                                                    or die(mysqli_error($this->con));       

    $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $old_email = $result['email'];
        $status = 0;
        $otp = rand(100000, 999999); // otp code
        if ($old_email == $email) {
            $result1 = mysqli_query($this->con, "UPDATE `users` SET `firstname` = '$fname', `lastname` = '$lname', `mobile` = '$mobile', `profile_pic` = '$profile_pic' 
                      WHERE `unique_id` = '$uid'") or die(mysqli_error($this->con));

            return $result1;
        } else {
            $result1 = mysqli_query($this->con, "UPDATE `users` SET `firstname` = '$fname',`lastname` = '$lname', `email` = '$email', `mobile` = '$mobile', `profile_pic` = '$profile_pic', `otp` = '$otp', `verified` = '$status'  
                      WHERE `unique_id` = '$uid'") or die(mysqli_error($this->con));

            return $result1;
        }


    } else {
        // user not found
        return false;
    }       

}
```

image picker in android fragment

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

save button code

```
String fname = eFirstName.getEditText().getText().toString();
String lname = eLastName.getEditText().getText().toString();
String email = eEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
String mobile = eMobile.getEditText().getText().toString();
String uid = user.get("uid");
String profile_pic = getStringImage(bitmap);

profileUpdate(fname,lname,email,mobile,aclass,school,uid,profile_pic);
```

onActivityResults code

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);
            eProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

Volley request code

```
private void ProfilePic(final String fname, final String lname, final String email, final String mobile, final String uid, final String profile_pic) {
       ..............................................
  ..........................................................

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "profile_update");
            params.put("fname", fname);
            params.put("lname", lname);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("mobile", mobile);              
            params.put("uid", uid);
            params.put("profile_pic", profile_pic);

            return params;
        }
```

Comment: Strange. I see no Volley code for posting an image. Nor do i see php code for receiving images.

Comment: all codes already here...i need help in php....i am sending image to base64string. now i want to convert image string and save to server directory and file url in mysql db

Comment: Nonsense. There is no code that sends an image. Nor is there php code that receives an image.

Comment: image picker for getting image from gallery then onActivityResults code is set bitmap in imageview. String profile_pic = getStringImage(bitmap); is getting image string and params.put("profile_pic", profile_pic); is sending image string...and i want to use file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($profile_pic)); this code to save image in server where $path is $path = "uploads/$uid.png"; but i don't know how to put this code in php..so change my php code...

Comment: `params.put("profile_pic", profile_pic); is sending image string.`. Nonsense. That only puts some content in params. There is no sending involved. The code that sends it is missing.